# How to use :put to append a variable at the end of the current line with vim

Tags: bash, vim

I have the following command, which I need to insert in a bash script:

```
vim file.txt -c ':let var=$foo' -c ':execute "normal! gg/string\<cr>V"' -c ":normal! d" -c ':execute "normal inewstring\<Esc>"' -c ':put =var'
```

What it does (or what I want it to do) is to use the variable `foo`, which is defined on the script, search for the first appearance of `string` select the whole line and delete it, then insert `newstring` and append the value of `foo` just after this new string. However, my code puts the value always in the next line, no matter if I change the x value in `:[x]put`.

As a novice in `vim` I'm not sure even if this way to achieve my goal is efficient, so any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Let's say that we have this input file:

```
$ cat file.txt
blah
string foo
string foo
blah
```

What I'm expecting to obtain (defining $foo="hello")  is:

```
 $ cat file.txt
 blah
 newstringhello
 string foo
 blah
```

Comment: You can't with `:put`. This is a job for `:substitute`, or even better for sed (if you are in bash context) as @Kent said.

Comment: To expand on what @LucHermitte said, `:put` works _linewise_.

Comment: @Sato Katsura What means _linewise_ in this context?

Comment: Same thing it means everywhere: `:h linewise`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a big vim fan, but if I were you, I won't do it with vim.

Since you didn't post the example input the desired output, I can only *guess* what do you want from your description.

Given that we have:

```
kent$  cat f
blah
string foo bar
string foo bar
blah
```

And `var="hello"`, the next sed one-liner changes the input file into:

```
kent$  sed "0,/string/{/string/s/.*/newString/};$ a \\$var" f
blah
newString
string foo bar
blah
hello
```

However I don't know if it is exactly what you wanted.

### update

```
kent$  sed "0,/string/{/string/s/.*/newString$var/}" f     
blah
newStringhello
string foo bar
blah
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for your answer. In fact what I'm expecting is to put hello just after newstring, i.e: newstringhello

Comment: @Panadestein take my input example, edit your question, add desired output, in comment I cannot know what format do you expect.

Comment: I hope now is understandable. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: you are really kind, your answer did the trick. Now my job is to understand the sed syntax.  Thanks a lot.